# Surely there should be some weather stripping on this sliding glass door?

Tags: weatherstripping

I've been on a quest to really weatherproof my home, built in 1962. There are sliding glass doors going out to the backyard and I just realized that it is completely open to the elements--and explains why flies are constantly coming in (I watched them fly through). Please see images here https://imgur.com/a/9l6pm5o I have one image of the bottom, where you can see light. The top on looks better but I believe it's probably open as there is some plate screwed in, but almost like it's been torn up.

When I search for sliding door weatherstripping, I don't find anything that seems remotely like it would fit. What am I missing here? Thank you!

Comment: I think because of way sliding doors open, they usually just use the fur like or rubber wipers.  I imagine the newer ones have better weatherstripping.  I think my old one just has the stripping between the two doors and uses two high outside sides and a smaller inside track for the top and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

It would be difficult to do.  You usually use brush style strips, mounted either under the door or the bottom of the door.  If installing under to go into the track, then installation would require you to remove the doors first.

Such as

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: "difficult to do" or is that a typo and you meant "not difficult to do"?  Because this seems like a pretty easy job

Comment: Thanks--would this fit though? My gap is irregularly shaped so I'm trying to figure out how it all would go together.